# How to set dynamic url in sencha touch using store?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, store

I am new for this platform, Now i am unable to set dyanimic url using category id and token.

What i want:
I have list different items, which have different ids but same token, token(tokent is same one user) getting from login phase. I want to get value accorading to category id from the server.
Here is the my model:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.CategoryDisplayModelMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
           /*'cat_id',*/
           'category',
           'name',
        ],

        belongsTo: "MyApp.model.CategoryDisplayModel"
    }
});
```

and **another related model is:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.CategoryDisplayModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires: ['MyApp.model.CategoryDisplayModelMenu'],
    config: {
        fields: [
         {name:'data', mapping: 'data'},
            {name:'name'},
            {name: 'category'},
            {name: 'author'},
        ],
    }
});
```

**What i am set in store, but could not work:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.CategoryValueStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.CategoryValueStore',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.CategoryDisplayModel'
    ],
     config: {
        model: 'MyApp.model.CategoryDisplayModel',
        storeId: 'categoriesvaluestore',

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'http://horror/myapp/api/word/searched_words/catID/'+ 1+'/'+ SDSILLYTOKEN+'/'+650773253e7f157a93c53d47a866204dedc7c363,
        noCache: false,           
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: ''
        }  }    }
});
```

**How to set above url, dynamic, cat id and token may be differnt.**

**But it works when i set these in store**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.ArchitectureDisplayStore',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Store', 
requires:[
'MyApp.view.Main'
],
config:
{
    model: 'MyApp.model.CategoryDisplayModel',
    autoLoad:true,
    id:'Category',
    proxy:
    {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'http://horror/myapp/api/word/searched_words/catID/1/SDSILLYTOKEN/650773253e7f157a93c53d47a866204dedc7c363', // file containing json data
          reader:
        {
                rootProperty:''
        }  } }
});
```

**In View , I set getting value on list like this:**

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.ArchitectureDisplayMain", {
  extend: 'Ext.Container',  
  alias: "widget.architecturewords", 

  config: {
   {      

       xtype: 'list',
       scrollable: true,       
       itemId: 'demolist',          
            itemTpl: [
            '<div><tpl for="data"><ul class="catList">{name} -test- {category}</ul> <ul>{author}</ul></tpl></div>'
            ],
            store: 'categoriesvaluestore',
          }
          }
          });
```

**My category display model:**

```
  Ext.define('MyApp.model.CategoryModelMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            'cat_id',
           'category_name',
        ],

        belongsTo: "MyApp.model.CategoryModel"
    }
});
```

and

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.CategoryModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: ['MyApp.model.CategoryModelMenu'],

    config: {
        fields: [
         {name:'data', mapping: 'data'},
              {name: 'cat_id'},
              {name: 'category_name'},
        ],
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Category', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
   alias: "widget.category", 
    config: {
        title: 'Stores',
        cls: 'category-data',
        scrollable: false,
        store: 'CategoryStore',
        itemTpl: [

        '<div class="categoryListings">',
          '<tpl for="data">',
          '<span onClick="catOption({cat_id})">{category_name}</span> ',
          '</tpl>',
          '</div>',

        ].join('')
    }
  //}
});

function catOption(id){

  console.log("ID--"+id);
var  tokan= '650773253e7f157a93c53d47a866204dedc7c363';
     Ext.Viewport.remove(Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem(), true);  
         Ext.Viewport.add([

             { xtype: 'wordsview' }

             ]);  

} and others
```

**In wordsview, I like to display respective words of clicked category.**

It is ok, when click this, first item of id p1, it shows next view.

Please tell me, How to get dynamic data accorading to its category id and token. please give some solution.Thank you advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you correctly

Let's say if you have category id and token in localStorage.

You can do like this

```
proxy:
{
   type: 'ajax',
   url : 'http://horror/myapp/api/word/searched_words/catID/'+localStorage.catId+'/SDSILLYTOKEN/'+localStorage.token,
     reader:{
       rootProperty:''
     }  
}
```

OR

Do as [@Alex posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825697/how-to-set-dynamic-url-in-sencha-touch-using-store/17832266#17832266). That is better way.. Like

```
function catOption(id){
  console.log("ID--"+id);
  var  token= '650773253e7f157a93c53d47a866204dedc7c363';

    var url = 'http://horror/myapp/api/word/searched_words/catID/'+id+'/SDSILLYTOKEN/'+token;

    Ext.getStore("categoriesvaluestore").getProxy().setUrl(url); 
    Ext.getStore("categoriesvaluestore").load();

     Ext.Viewport.remove(Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem(), true);  
     Ext.Viewport.add({ xtype: 'wordsview' });  
}
```

Comment: I dont understand, How to get catId and Token from view to store.

Comment: you have catId and Token values in view !!?

Comment: yes, I have. But but i did not any idea, how to pass catid and token from view to store.

Comment: Ok, please see in Edit on my Problem.

Comment: Ok, i can see catId in catOption function.. so set catId in localStorage.. like this 'localStorage.catID = id;' within catOption function. But i can't find token.. anyway do the same for token.. and set the url as i posted

Comment: I faced this error on console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getProxy' of undefined

Comment: Thank you so much, it is quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When accessing your Store from your View or anywhere else, you can dinamically change the Url this way:

```
var stProxy = Ext.StoreMgr.get("myStore").getProxy();
stProxy.setUrl("http://the.new.url");
Ext.StoreMgr.set("myStore").setProxy(stProxy);
```

--

The particular problem in your scenario is that you may have to populate your list manually. If you want a List to include the result of calling the same Store with different URLs, I suggest to build a new local Store loading the content of all iterations. Then make the List "store" property be this global Store.